# Face Type Detection

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, core-image

I have to detect the face type - oval, rectangular, diamond, hear shape in my application. I have done the face detection using open CV and coreimage framework, but it does not tell the type of the face.

what I actually need to do is detect the type of the face and show a celebrity face having the same type of face shape displaying your face matches with her/him.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "type of the face"? Are you trying to match the detected face with a set of predefined faces?

Comment: Where is your problem? what do you have?

Comment: You need to define features that map the face to the type you find: what makes a face rectangular? maybe a certain aspect ratio or ... . You should define these so you can find the face type.

Comment: type of the face means oval, rectangular, diamond, heart shape.

Comment: how do i define those aspect ratios as face detection only tells about eyes and mouth. I do not get the actual face shape.

Comment: I'ts hard to understand what do you mean by a "diamond" face. Can you give an example?

btw, a rule of thumb says that when it's hard to define the problem and measure it (for example, what exactly makes a face diamond shape), you should go for learning approaches.

Comment: leave diamond for now, tell me about oval if you can

Comment: Have API fees get shape face?

Comment: you can find face shapes using dlib's face shape predictor ans using mathematical calculations, finding length of forehead, jawline, length of face, angle of jawline.
i have implemented this please do check my repo.
> https://github.com/Nitish1206/face_shape_without_model

Answer (score 1):

You have to train a face recognizer for your four classes: oval, rectangular, diamond, heart shape. Therefore you will have to find examples of many different people with that face shape. Give each of your classes a label and train a normal FaceRecognizer with that.

If you want to get an idea about the actual steps check out the [gender classification with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html), and do exactly the same. In gender classification it is done for 2 classes (male / female). You have to do it for 4 classes (4 different shape types).

Comment: I'm not sure that will work without a proper shape descriptor.

Comment: Yes it will. I have successfully used it for Gender classification, Age estimation and race detection. Like all these algorithms it will work with a certain accuracy after a proper training. There is no need to make it more complicated.